# Remove decimal from currency

Tags: c#, string-formatting, currency

I am converting data for an export.

The file shows data in cents, not dollars.

So 1234.56 needs to be printed as 123456

Is there a way to do that with `string.Format`?

Or is the only solution to multiply by 100?

Comment: And a -1 because... what?  Just downvoting doesn't exactly help.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: +1 (offsetting downvote). Nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: @QuinnWilson, because the system consuming this file expects amounts in cents, not dollars...sometimes.  Thus, it has to be configurable.  Using a string.Format string, seemed to be a solution that could solve this when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string.Replace(".", string.empty). But that isn't exactly localized. You could add in cases where you check for "," as well for international currency. But that's what I would do.

[Edit]

Also just found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

The "N" numeric specifier allows you to change the symbol used to separate whole number and decimal parts.

```
<code>

decimal num = 123.456m;
NumberFormatInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
ci.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = " "; // You can't use string.Empty here, as it throws an exception.
string str = num.ToString("N", ci).Replace(" ", string.Empty);

</code>
```

Something like that should do the trick, and is localized!

Comment: Sucks that you can't use an empty string as the seperator, but this seems to work pretty well.  I had to create a new culture though, as existing ones were read-only.

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit the post to include that you can't use an empty separator.

Answer (score 2):

That's a rendering issue.  Certainly multiplying by 100 to get cents will do the job.

The United States uses the decimal point to separate dollars from cents.  But not all countries do that.  Your "multiply by 100" solution is only correct for currencies that use 100 fractional units to represent a single whole.  (Not the case in Japan for yen.)

Comment: That is why I want a solution that is NOT multiplying by 100, which is why I was looking for a `string.Format` solution.

Comment: Check out my solution on the bottom; it's localized and clean.

Answer (score 0):

If it is that simple, just do `String.Replace('.','');`

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the values will always have 2 Decimal Positions then do this it's very simple

```
var strVar = 1234.56;
var somevalues   = string.Format("{0:######}", strVar * 100);
```

`output = 123456`